# Debugging with Eclipse using multiple windows

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I usually run a dual-monitor setup, so I have two Eclipse windows open for the same workspace, displaying different files. When I'm debugging and a breakpoint is hit, Eclipse switches to the "Debug" perspective, but it also shows the file/line where the breakpoint is in both of my windows. This occurs even if the file containing the breakpoint was open in one window but not the other (before the breakpoint was hit).

This is really annoying.

How can I have Eclipse only show the file containing the breakpoint in one window? Ideally, it would choose which window based on where the file is open already. If it's not already open somewhere, I don't really care which window it pops up in.

Comment: Do you really have two windows open? Or detached windows? If eclipse goes into debug only one of the windows switches perspective to debug in my eclipse ( 3.5 Build id: 20100218-1602)

Comment: What's the difference? I'm not running two instances of Eclipse. I open one workspace, then I open the second window by going to the Window menu => New Window.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and do not have this issue, only 1 of the opened windows switches to debug perspective and opens the file.
Could be some setting in Preferenes->Run/Debug ?

Comment: Maybe let the team know about it ?

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: This problem occurrs when you manually switch both windows to the debug perspective. I do this when I want to debug my client in the left window and my server in the right window, but I always end up debugging both programs in both windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another workspace and in that workspace create a new project from the same src code (same files in file system) of the one in your current project in your current workspace.
That would let you stop on one breakpoint without the other window stopping their too.
Notice that after you make some code modifications in one project you'd have to refresh the other project for those changes to apply in it.

Comment: That sounds like an awful, hacky fix that's worse than the problem itself.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse switches to the debug perspective for all windows the debug perspective has been opened once (i.e. the little icon on the right top corner is available). If you close that perspective (switch to another perspective is not sufficient), it won't switch to it anymore on that window.

At least, that's the behaviour I observed on Kepler (I know, that question is older but just came across, maybe it still helps someone).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
In Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching->Launch Configurations enable "Apply window working set(s)"

Personally I find this more efficient than creating two workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the Debug perspective (righ-click on the little icon on the right top corner) worked for me.
I'm using Oxygen and I have the following settings in the Run/Debug Preferences:

- Open the associated perspective when launching: Never
- Open the associated perspective when an application suspends: Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you select the sources for Debugging by "File System Directory" instead of by "Java Project". To change this go to ***Run=>Debug Configuration=>Add Sources=Button: ADD...=>Java Project*** and select your Projects.

Make sure, that the added sources are found first by moving them to the top.

Answer (score 0):

To disable multiple debugging in multiple windows in eclipse, go to Windows > Preferences > Run/Debug and uncheck *Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit*